# How to use ObjectSizeGreaterThan and ObjectSizeLessThan xml tags for AWS S3 command 'PutBucketLifeCycleConfiguration"?

Tags: css, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, s3cmd

Trying with a json input like this:

```html
{
  "Rules": [
    {
      "Expiration": {
        "Date": "2023-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"
      },
      "ID": "id1",
      "Filter": {
          "And": {
            "Tags": [
              {
                "Key": "k1",
                "Value": "k1val1"
              },
              {
                "Key": "k1u",
                "Value": "k1vadl1"
              }
            ],
            "ObjectSizeGreaterThan": 100,
            "ObjectSizeLessThan": 1000
          }
      },
      "Status": "Enabled"
    }
  ]
}
```

However, I am getting an error like this from the aws client:

```
Parameter validation failed:
Unknown parameter in LifecycleConfiguration.Rules[0].Filter.And: "ObjectSizeGreaterThan", must be one of: Prefix, Tags
```

Any idea why I get this error and how to correct it?

Comment: I wonder if you need to include a `Prefix`? See the `<And>` example on: [Lifecycle configuration elements - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/intro-lifecycle-rules.html)

Comment: Including prefix or not, doesn't make a difference, I still get the same error. So, the actual issue that I am facing is how do I use the objectsize related tags in the json input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be working but only with the latest cli version `aws-cli/2.7.30`

I am getting the same error on `aws-cli/1.19.39`

```
{
    "Rules": [
      {
        "Expiration": {
            "Date": "2024-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"
        },
        "ID": "123",
        "Filter": {
          "And": {
            "Prefix": "sricli",
            "Tags": [
              {
                "Key": "ke",
                "Value": "k1"
              },
              {
                "Key": "je",
                "Value": "k2"
              }
            ],
            "ObjectSizeGreaterThan": 102400,
            "ObjectSizeLessThan": 204800
          }
        },
        "Status": "Enabled"
      }
    ]
  }
```

Sri

Comment: That didn't work either. Issue is it is not able to recognize the objectsize tag properties.

"Parameter validation failed:
Unknown parameter in LifecycleConfiguration.Rules[0].Filter: "ObjectSizeGreaterThan", must be one of: Prefix, Tag, And
Unknown parameter in LifecycleConfiguration.Rules[0].Filter: "ObjectSizeLessThan", must be one of: Prefix, Tag, And"

Comment: Are you using cli or the console? Have you tried using the console?

Comment: Yes cli. Don't have access to console.

Comment: I see your issue. I am able to create the policy using the console but I am unable to see the value of `ObjectSizeGreaterThan` and `ObjectSizeLessThan` when i perform `get-bucket-lifecycle-configuration`. I will keep you posted if I can find a solution.

Comment: I have updated the answer, please check and let me know if it works.

Comment: Well, yes. It did work with newer aws version. Big thanks for that, Sri!!!